# How to open a web page after reboot

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, installation, reboot, runonce

I'm creating an installer of sorts. It's a C# application that upgrades prerequisites on a system before a new ClickOnce application is installed. The final step is to reboot the system and I'd like it to open up the ClickOnce application's deployment URL after it restarts. I tried adding the following to the CurrentUser RunOnce registry key, but IE didn't start up:

```
start iexplore http://myInstallationUrl.com/publish.htm
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and offer an approach that will?

Comment: ClickOnce should manage the dependencies for you... No?

Comment: Try `start http://myInstallationUrl.com/publish.htm` (it should start the default browser). Or `iexplore http://myInstallationUrl.com/publish.htm` to open it in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user had answered this question but it's now gone so I'm filling it back in. Thanks to him/her and Alexey for providing the answer:

What worked for me was adding "iexplore http://myInstallationUrl.com/publish.htm". It just didn't like start + iexplore. In my case it was safe to assume the user would have internet explorer installed. I haven't tried "start http://myInstallationUrl.com/publish.htm" to verify it works but being able to open the URL in the default browser also seems valuable.